# 'the Egypt's Desert' or 'the Egyptian Desert'?

Tags: definite-article, punctuation, possessives

"A series of caves are found at a site named Wadi Gawasis in the  [Egypt's/ Egyptian] desert"

I don't find any technical difference in both options but still my book says **Egyptian** is correct answer. Is there any rule or should questions like this be solved by knowledge conventional terms? It is also interesting to note that we don't say Nepalian mountains or Chinian hill stations.

I guess that there are specific regions where *tian* should be used. If so, then please share a list where this usage is observed.

EDIT: Original Phrase

"In 2004, a team of archaeologists discovered the remains of shipyard in a  series of caves at a site named Wadi Gawasis in the  [Egypt's/ Egyptian] desert"

Comment: Please double check that you have copied the phrase exactly. Could you also include the sentences that precede this one, please? Context will help users provide better answers.

Comment: If you have reproduced the question and answer exactly, the authors are in error and you should consider discarding this text.

Comment: *Qumran Caves **are a series of caves**, some natural, some artificial, **found** around the archaeological site of Qumran **in the Judaean Desert** of the West Bank.* [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qumran_Caves)

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed, but it's tempting to suppose OP has just missed the last letter of ***deserts***. In which case I guess it's *still* a bad text, because someone has mistaken ideas about whether we should refer to, say, ***Irish peat-bogs*** or ***Ireland's peat-bogs***.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP has indeed copied the question incorrectly, but that the objective is to identify the choice that does not require the definite article, which he has omitted in copying.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Please check the edited question. P.S. sorry for the delay.

Comment: @ParthMaske better late than never, now the sentence makes more semantic and grammatical sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In 2004, a team of archaeologists discovered the remains of shipyard in a series of caves at a site named Wadi Gawasis in the [Egypt's/ Egyptian] desert"

If the above  is the correct sentence,  including the correct placement of the brackets [ and ], then only *Egyptian* is correct, because we don't use the definite article before *Egypt* except in such statements as *the Egypt that I knew* or *the Egypt of the future*.

And,  the possessive '*the Egypt's desert'  is always  wrong.  You can say 'Egypt's desert'  (without the article).

PS- It's true that we don't say "Nepalian mountains or Chinian hill stations," but we do use the correct adjectival form and say "Nepalese mountains" and "Chinese hill stations."

Comment: +1. I think this is what the problem was trying to emphasize.

Comment: @Alan Carmack If there was no "the", then would it be possible to differentiate between the choices?

Comment: @Parth The noun phrase *Egyptian desert* requires the article.

Answer (score 1):

> Egypt's desert

is unambiguous and refer's to a desert under Egypt's ownership.

> Egyptian desert

needs further context since it could mean the same as "Egypt's desert" but could also mean a "desert of the Egyptian" type, for example if there were different types of deserts.

Just as

> Parisian cafe

does not necessarily mean a cafe in Paris, but a certain style of cafe.

In your example, the only possible answer is

> Egyptian desert
>   A series of caves are found at a site named Wadi Gawasis in *the Egyptian* desert.

since the determiner "the" is being used, if "the was left out, then the answer would be

> Egypt's desert
>   A series of caves are found at a site named Wadi Gawasis in *Egypt's* desert.

Comment: No.  Egypt's desert is quite ambiguous.  As I pointed out in my answer, Egypt's desert and Algeria's desert are the same desert.  Mali's desert, Libya's desert, Mauritania's desert.  Still all the same desert -- the Sahara.  In this case Egypt's does not imply ownership.  It implies "desert that covers some or all of Egypt."

Comment: @EllieK I think if one refers to Egypt's desert it is a reference to the portion of the Sahara which belongs to Egypt in the same way that Egypt's Nile would refer to the portion of the Nile within Egypt and not the full extent of the Nile.

Comment: I would call that the Egyptian Nile not Egypt's Nile.  Egypt's Nile?  Seriously?  You're thinking of "Egypt's portion of the Nile."  Which simply can be called the Egyptian Nile.  Egypt's Nile, by the way, extends all way into Sudan.  Egypt's Nile and Sudan's Nile are both the same river -- the Nile.

Comment: Please don't respond with nitpicks about Red Nile and White Nile.

Comment: Please check the edited question. P.S. sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

A good question because it is difficult to explain.  There is only one desert in Egypt, the Sahara.  If you say Egypt's desert you are then referring to the Sahara desert.  Whether you mean to refer to the entire Sahara desert by calling it Egypt's desert or the particular area of the Sahara encompassed by Egypt is not clear without accompanying context.

Referring the Sahara as a whole ...

> Egypt's desert[, the Sahara,] is vast, stretching beyond Egypt's borders and covering the whole of North Africa.

Or the Egyptian portion of the Sahara ...

> Egypt's desert, unlike the rest of the Sahara, is rocky and relatively moist.

However, the following is unclear.  Do we mean all of the Sahara or just the Egyptian Sahara?

> Egypt's desert is rocky and relatively moist.

"The Egyptian desert," on the other hand, refers specifically to desert areas under the control of Egypt or, if it were the case, the whole of a smaller desert contained entirely within Egypt.  The Egyptian desert ends at the border with Sudan and the Sudanese desert begins.

The following is not ambiguous...

> The Egyptian desert is rocky and relatively moist.

You could also say...

> Egyptian desert is rocky and relatively moist.

You should not say...

> The Egyptian desert is vast, stretching beyond Egypt's borders..."

The Egyptian desert cannot stretch beyond Egypt's borders.  At that point it ceases to be Egyptian desert.

Comment: The "Egyptian Desert" would work if this was a known proper noun, for example the "Caspian Sea", where the possessive "Caspian" is simply part of its name.

Comment: At the very least, Egypt has the [Western and Eastern deserts](http://teacherweb.com/ON/RickHansenPublicSchool/v/apt5.aspx) - they pretty well *must* be separate deserts, since they're separated by the Nile.

Comment: For further clarification you can think of it like this.  "Are Egypt's desert and Algeria's desert the same desert?"  Answer: Yes.  "Are the Egyptian desert and the Algerian desert the same desert."  Answer: They are _part_ of the same desert but the Algerian desert is sandy and the Egyptian desert is rocky.

Comment: No need for desert nitpicking.  No one is interested in the minutia of sub deserts within the Sahara.  Egypt's desert is the Sahara.  So is Algeria's.  Please save the nitpicks for geography.stackexhange.

Comment: Please check the edited question. P.S. sorry for the delay.